# how do I include a file which is inside other directory

Tags: php, syntax-error

My file lies in /var/www/spywgc/adm/index.php folder ....
and the file i want to include lies in var/www/spywgc/adm/rpt/lib_pivot.php

I want to include lib_pivot.php in index.php.....
The lib_pivot.php interns include a file var/www/spywgc/lib_gen file.....

I wrote a syntax of `<?php require_once('./rpt/lib_pivot.php'); ?>` in index.php file...
but, it keeps giving me error....

Someone please explain me what to do.

Comment: `..` (two dots) takes the path into the parent directory. `.` means the current directory

Answer (score 3):

close. try:

```
<?php require_once('../rpt/lib_pivot.php'); ?>
```

Comment: @vincy haha ah okay, in that case it's just <?php require_once('rpt/lib_pivot.php'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

> require_once('/var/www/spywgc/rpt/lib_pivot.php');

will sort you out, probably. i.e. the full path rather than a relative one.

Comment: It's missing a leading / anyways, so it's a relative path that's unlikely to exist on the OP's server.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that the lib_pivot lies in child directory and not the parent directory....please check the wuestion again....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require_once('../rpt/lib_pivot.php'); ?>
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention lib_pivot lies in child directory....not parent.....please check the question again....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/rpt/lib_pivot.php'); ?>
```

If lib_pivot.php includes another file with relative path you’ll have to use `__FILE__` there as well.

You said

> The lib_pivot.php interns include a file var/www/spywgc/lib_gen file.....

Is it lib_gen.php?

The `lib_pivot.php` will have to include as well, like

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/rpt/lib_gen.php');
```

Comment: Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../rpt/lib_pivot.php' (include_path='.:/usr/PEAR:/home/facetime/PEAR:/usr/bin/pear_old') in /var/www/html/spywgc/adm/index1.php on line 3

Comment: As you changed the paths in your question this question was no longer valid. I changed it now to be for the current question text. `index.php` is to include `./rpt/lib_pivot.php`.